# Handling 302 redirect while logging to site using Python + urllib

Tags: python, asp.net, urllib

I'm using Python 3.2 and urllib and trying to login to site using following code:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import ProxyHandler, build_opener, install_opener
import http.cookiejar

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': '  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0'}


#proxy
proxy_login = 'my_login'
proxy_password = 'my_proxy'
proxy_address = 'proxy_address'

proxy = ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://%s:%s@%s' %(proxy_login,  proxy_password, proxy_address)})

login = 'login'
password = 'password'

app_link = 'http://app_link'

cookie = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(proxy, urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
install_opener(opener)
```

As I see in FireBug, firstly I should GET the Login.aspx page to set up __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATE. It's not a problem:

```
def get_login_data(log_page):
    parsed_login_page = BeautifulSoup(log_page)
    view_state = parsed_login_page.find('input', id="__VIEWSTATE").attrs['value']
    event_validation = parsed_login_page.find('input', id="__EVENTVALIDATION").attrs['value']

    return {'__EVENTTARGET': 'btnContinue', '__EVENTVALIDATION': event_validation, 
            '__VIEWSTATE': view_state, 'txtLogin': login, 'txtPassword': password}

#getting nessesary data from the login page
req = urllib.request.Request("%s/Login.aspx" %app_link, headers = headers)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('cp1251')
data = get_login_data(page)
sendData = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode()
```

I see in browser, that there's 302 redirect on Login.aspx page when logging.

```
POST    Login.aspx      302 Found
GET     OrderOptions.aspx   200 OK
```

As I undrestand, browser makes POST Login.aspx request, receives .ASPXAUTH cookie and then GET next page, OrderOptions.aspx.
How can I do the same? I've tried this:

```
req2 = urllib.request.Request("%s/Login.aspx" %app_link, sendData, headers)
resp2 = urllib.request.urlopen(req2)
page2 = resp2.read().decode('cp1251')
```

But it doesn't work: looks like my req2 POST requests becomes GET, just loads Login.aspx again and I don't receive any cookie.

```
>>> req2.get_method()
'POST'
>>> resp2._method
'GET'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Obviously you are putting a lot of effort but have you looked at the requests library? It handles all of this so much better, i.e. proxies, authentication, redirection, sessions, cookies.

Comment: @mhawke, I've heard about it and will use it, if there's no decision. I just haven't have any problems with urllib before facing with ASP.NET.